# How to define optional variables in Terraform with default values defined in Consul

Tags: terraform, consul

I have a Terraform script with some variables populated from Consul. I want to use this script in two different scenarios:

- Scenario 1. Everything goes right using default values from Consul.
- Scenario 2. I need to override some variables.

I've checked Terraform documentation and noticed that I can't use a variable defined in Consul as a default value for some another variable. So I ended up with following workaround:

```
## vars.tf
## emulating undefined value using "null" string
variable "my_optional_variable" { default = "null" } 

## main.tf
my_optional_variable = "${var.my_optional_variable == "null" ? data.consul_keys.my_optional_variable : var.my_optional_variable}"
```

Can somebody show me a better way to do it? **How to avoid a hack with a "null" string?**

Thanks

Answer (score 20):

Another option is [`coalesce`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#coalesce-string1-string2-) which works with empty strings so is slightly better than your `"null"` string.

Given your scenario or a similar case with two variables/data sources

```
variable "my_default_value" {
  default = "CentOS 7"
}
variable "my_optional_variable" {
  default = ""
}
```

You can take the *"first non-empty value from the given arguments. At least two arguments must be provided."*

```
data "openstack_images_image_v2" "bastion_image" {
  name = "${coalesce(var.my_optional_variable, var.my_default_value)}"
}
```

Comment: The best answer! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

if your optional variable needs to come externally or from a declared resource you can use `count` and ternaries to accomplish this.

```
variable "my_variable_id" {
    type = string
    default = ""
}

resource "cloud_resource" "my_resource" {
    count = var.my_variable == "" ? 1 : 0
    other_params = {...}
}

resource "dependent_cloud_resource" "my_other_resource" {
    other_resource_id = var.my_variable_id == "" ? cloud_resrouce.my_resource[0].id : var.my_variable_id
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [override file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/override.html). So, if you have `vars.tf` containing:

```
variable "my_optional_variable" {
  default = "null"
}
```

And `override.tf` that contains:

```
variable "my_optional_variable" {
  default = "not null"
}
```

Then `${var.my_optional_variable}` should equal `not null`. Override files are loaded last and merged into your configuration. Rather then appended together like other `.tf` files in the directory.